# как сделать select с подписью "сортировать по:"

Tags: html

не могу разобраться как сделать select с подписью "сортировать по: " и option со значениями, но в option не должно быть полной записи "сортировать по: умолчанию", только "умолчанию"

Пробовал, сделать так, но не получилось:

```
<select>
    <option label="Умолчанию" value="1" selected>Сортировать по умолчанию</option>
    <option label="Дате" value="2">Сортировать по Дате</option>
    <option label="Времени" value="3">Сортировать по Времени</option>
    <option label="Значению" value="4">Сортировать по Значению</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 2):

> .... не должно быть полной записи...

Ну, так и не пишите полную запись:

```html
Сортировать по: <select>
  <option label="Умолчанию" value="1" selected>умолчанию</option>
  <option label="Дате" value="2">Дате</option>
  <option label="Времени" value="3">Времени</option>
  <option label="Значению" value="4">Значению</option>
</select>
```